# how to change the text of navbar link in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

How can I replace the Link text on active-admin navbar for a model?

I have a model: `OpportunityConsultantPairing`, which I'm registering in active-admin as follow:

```
ActiveAdmin.register OpportunityConsultantPairing do

  controller do
    before_filter { @page_title = "Project Pairings" }
  end

end
```

setting `@page_title` only changes the Title, what I want to do however is to change both the title, as well as the navbar-link text as shown below:

[image]

How can one go about this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ActiveAdmin.register OpportunityConsultantPairing do
 menu label: "Project Pairings"

  controller do
    before_filter { @page_title = "Project Pairings" }
  end

end
```

for more info check here:- http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser, as: 'User' do
 # code...
end
```

Navigation label will be changes as 'user/users' instead of 'admin_users'

routes will be configured automatically as '.../admin/users' instead of '.../admin/admin_users'.